# How to find the total number of downloads a gig had in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, model

This is the models relationship i have

For **Purchase.rb**

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gig
  belongs_to :buyer, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :seller, class_name: 'User'
end
```

For **User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :purchases, foreign_key: 'buyer_id'
  has_many :gigs, through: :purchases, source: :buyer
  has_many :gigs
  has_many :sales, foreign_key: 'seller_id', class_name: 'Purchase'
end
```

For **Gig.rb**

```
class Gig < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :purchases
  has_many :buyers, through: :purchases
  has_many :sellers, through: :purchases
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Now i can do

1.`current_user.gigs.count` to show the number of uploaded gigs by the current_user

2.`current_user.purchases.count` to show how many downloads the current_user did.

3.`@gig.purchases.count` how many times the chosen gig was downloaded

> **Question:** If a user uploads a gig,as in **code 3 above**,i can show the number of times this gig was downloaded,but now I want to
>   show if the user lets say uploads 3-7 gigs,i want to show the whole number of
>   downloads he got,from all of his gigs.

I though about something like that `current_user.gigs.purchases.count`,to count all the downloads his all gigs got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just query the amount directly through the user's purchases and sum them, like this:

```
current_user.gigs.map{|gig| gig.purchases.size}.sum
```

or in your model user.rb

```
def total_gigs_sold
  gigs.map{|gig| gig.purchases.size}.sum
end
```

You should choose your names wisely too. Is every download a purchase?
Wouldnt that make it very easy to say

```
current_user.sales.size
```

is the same as the number of times a gig was sold(/downloaded)?

Comment: You are right,that will work as well,i'm sorry its a bit off topic,but how would you show the user how many downloads all his gigs got for example  just for today?

Comment: `current_user.sales.where{|s| s.created_at.to_date == Date.today}.size` should work

Answer (score 0):

Using a counter cache may be better served as it will reduce the number of database calls.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer, counter_cache: :count_of_orders
end
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
end
```